# The seconds displayed on the Windows 10 lockscreen clock are not updating

Tags: windows-10, time, lock-screen

When I go to my lockscreen, Windows shows the time, but the seconds don't update. I took a screencap of my lockscreen and highlighted in red the part that isn't working. Basically, the minutes and hours update fine, but the seconds are stuck at whatever value it was when I locked the screen. When the minute updates, the seconds seem to get set to either 00 or 01. Switching to a 12-hour clock did not fix it.

Is there any way I can get the seconds working?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock screen displays the short time. By default a short time pattern does not include seconds.

The lock screen design is therefore based on the principle that displaying seconds is not necessary (and unexpected).

Comment: If seconds do not work why does it let me have the lock screen display seconds in the first place?  Sounds poorly designed.

Answer (score 1):

---

### Edit: Added link to my submittal of this bug on the Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/Fb6zs8

Hello The Supreme Leader,

Love your lockscreen background.

What you have done with the time format is the same thing I have done. It's a semi-bug in Windows 10.

Reproduction Method:

1. In a command prompt or Run dialog, launch the Intl.cpl (Region Control Panel)
2. In the Short time drop-down box, you will see 5 entries "HH:mm:ss","HH:mm", "h:mm tt", "hh:mm tt", and "H:mm". "HH:mm:ss" is only showing up because that is the current setting. If you were to select any other options than "HH:mm:ss", "HH:mm:ss" disappears from the menu choices and only 4 are available.
3. Click on "Additional Settings..."
4. Navigate to the Time tab.
5. In the "Time formats" section, we see the Short time text box/drop-down menu. Here, if "HH:mm:ss" is still set, we see 5 options available. Likely, you did the same thing I did in the past. Originally only have 4 options available, I manually typed in "HH:mm:ss" and pressed apply to save that new value.
6. After closing that customize format dialog, you will be able to press apply on the Region Control Panel dialog. If that dialog did NOT update to show "HH:mm:ss", pressing Apply or OK again on this dialog will wipe the previous setting. Press cancel on this screen to close it.
7. Relaunch Intl.cpl
8. Navigate to the Administrative tab
9. Click on "Copy settings..."
10. Check the box for "Welcome screen and system accounts"
11. Click OK to close the "Welcome screen and new accounts settings" dialog
12. Click Cancel to close the Region Control Panel dialog. Now the lock screen upon boot-up and when your user account locks will show this time format.

Do you concur that this is either how you got here or that your settings represent this?

The taskbar does not show this, however, clicking on the clock brings up the time/calendar menu. This does show the clock and update every second. Strangely, each of my calendar appointments for tomorrow show seconds on the time. They are all wrong. In fact, each of the seconds shown are the same, and they were the value of the live clock when the menu loaded. So I loaded the menu at 43, and the clock shows 44.

Clearly Microsoft has not tested this all that well. Some parts of the OS are able to pick up on a custom time and update every second. Other parts are hard-coded to only update every one minute, or just flat out break and show incorrect data.

So now that we have all the data laid out for reference, back to your actual question. The lock screen is in fact properly querying the time format you have specified. It just is not updating at the proper interval.
I came across your post because I was looking for a way to manually modify the update rate to show the proper seconds on the clock. Sorry I don't have a fix, but perhaps this documentation of the bug scenario will help us find a fix, or workaround.

[image: Screenshot of Short time Time Format Drop-Down(combo box) in Windows 10 1703 15063]

[image: Windows 10 Time/Calendar pop-up menu showing live seconds on top and the seconds after each appointment. Note, the seconds on each appointment are all incorrect. They are only the value of seconds from the live clock.]